# How to make bootstrap panels resizeable

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to allow to change panel height by dragging panel footer using mouse.

I tried `resize: vertical` style in code below but it does not allow to drag panel footer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        .panel-resizable {
            resize: vertical;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body panel-resizable" style="height:80px">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Band1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body panel-resizable">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Band2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add `overflow: auto;` ( in case if you want to hide your overflow just make the `overflow:hidden;` )
working here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        .panel-resizable {
            resize: vertical;
          overflow: auto
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body panel-resizable" style="height:80px">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Band1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body panel-resizable">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Band2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. How to resize panel by dragging panel footer in any place ? In this sample resize can performed only using panel content right bottom corner.

Comment: Yes. Whole panel footer can used to resize

Comment: It does not allow to change height less than specified in `style="height:80px"`  How to fix this so that panel content can resized to zero-height ?

Comment: you can check this link if you want to resize while panel http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/resize-textarea-jquery-javascript.html

Comment: If second panel height is specified, it does not allow to resize at all. Without second panel height it does not allow to resize to 0 content height. I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601106/how-to-allow-to-resize-panel-height-to-0

Answer (score 5):

Resize does not work without setting the overflow.

```
.panel-resizable {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qd3236no/

Comment: This fiddle does not allow to decrease panel contents height. In Internet explorer it does not allow resize at all. How to fix this ? I posted it as separate question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601106/how-to-allow-to-resize-panel-content-height-to-0?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can only resize if overflow is set to something, like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/qvw69r5L/

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: This fiddle does not allow to decrease panel height. In Internet Explorer it does not allow any resize. How to fix this ?

Comment: Internet Explorer does not support the resize property. You must use something like jQueryUI to achieve this effect in any version of IE, including Edge at this time.