# How to allow to resize panel content height to 0

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

Panel heights are specified initially using inline styles.
All panels content heights should allowed to resize to any value starting at 0

I tried code below using

```
        .panel-resizable {
            resize: vertical;
          overflow: auto
        }
```

but it does not allow to resize panel header lest than initial height.

How to allow to resize all panels to any size ?

Some jquery, jquery ui other other plugin can used instead of bootstrap if it solves the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        .panel-resizable {
            resize: vertical;
          overflow: auto
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body panel-resizable" style="height:180px">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Band1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body panel-resizable" style="height:280px">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Band2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, I created a JSFiddle and it works perfectly I can resize it to a minimum of 1px height. https://jsfiddle.net/x0gyyp3s/1/

Comment: I tried you fiddle in desktop chrome. It does not allow to decrease heights. It allows only to increase heights. In Internet Explorer it does not allow any  resize, resize icon does not appear.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize IE does not support the resize property.

Comment: Anytime `height` is set, the browser will use the new height as min-height upon resizing. So I dont think this problem is solveable without a kind of hack (there is plenty of those out there) that we cannot be sure actually will work with different browsers in the future.

Comment: @SeanWessell, no - but I think we finally can consider IE as "deprecated" :)

Comment: @davidkonrad I can force users to use Chrome. What kind of hack should used to allow to set height to 0, something like http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/resize-textarea-jquery-javascript.html ?  Or is it better to use drad and drop for such resize ?

Comment: @Andrus, have posted an answer with such example - only tested in chrome and FF though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason (not sure why, still investigating) you can overrule the browsers resize `min-height` (== current `style.height` value) for the resizeable *if* you add a pseudo class like this :

```
.panel-resizable:active {
    height: 1px;
}
```

*and* remove the hardcoded inline `style="height:180px;"` - initial height can still be set by the CSS :

```
.panel-resizable {
   resize: vertical;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color:#f00;
   height: 180px;
}
```

the fiddle from comments updated -> **https://jsfiddle.net/x0gyyp3s/2/**

Comment: clicking inside panel contents changes panel height to 1px. How to fix this so that panel will keep its height ?

Comment: I posted related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644134/how-to-allow-to-resize-panels-on-zero-height I swithed to jquery-ui resizable since zero height resize looks not possbile in other ways.